# SharePoint 2013 Search Crawl - Same Key Error

Tags: 2013, search, crawl

I am getting the below crawl error when search tries to crawl 2 site collections:

The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service. ( Error from SharePoint site: *** An item with the same key has already been added., CorrelationID: 9fe8c99d-16a9-a04f-6dfc-8d129b83c3fa; SearchID = A9836C8D-CBD7-434E-BC11-149D24EDE52A )

What does this error mean and how this can be resolved?

Comment: Check the log entry using the correlation id for more info.

Comment: As Buzab suggests check the ULS logs for more information. If standard logs are not providing enough info. Increase the verbosity of the logs to verboseex by running this SP PS command: "Set-SPLogLevel -EventSeverity verbose -TraceSeverity verboseex" to set it back to standard after troubleshooting run the "Clear-SPLogLevel"

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by a duplicate Group name in the site.